# Google API for objective-c app

Tags: objective-c, api

is there a way to get emails from google, send emails, and add contacts to the address book using the google API?

I'm doing an obj-c mac application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find luck here
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: Upon closer look I don't see gmail either.  That may be a strategic decision to exclude it?!  I can only tell you I'm using the analytics API and it's good.

Comment: Interesting.... Yeah the other examples are great. But no mail? Do you know another ways I can get gmail?

Answer (score 2):

You can access mail from Google (and most other mail providers) via IMAP and mail can be sent via SMTP. You can use the [Pantomime Framework](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime/) for these protocols.